# Uber rush API returning html page in response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

Using uber rush API I've successfully created authorization token. But when I try to create quote all I get is HTML page. I am making http request from iOS Objective C. This is how I am making http request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/v1/deliveries/quote", kLiveURL]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUberRushAccessTokenKey]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lul", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (data) {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"dataString: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"httpResponse: %@", response);
    }
}];
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: Are you using the sandbox environment? What is the full url? I am unable to duplicate this as the following throws a json validation error as expected: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' -X POST 'https://api.uber.com/v1/deliveries/quote' -d '{ }'

Comment: I tried to use sandbox environment but it gives me error the "method_not_supported" for given endpoints. For live I am using 'https://uber.com/v1/deliveries/quote'

Comment: What is the actual response content? I am not able to reproduce.

Comment: this is the response I am getting no matter what environment (sandbox or live) I choose:
`{
    code = "method_not_allowed";
    message = "Method not supported for this endpoint.";
}`

Comment: Ok, may bad. I was putting two `//` in my code that's why I was getting "endpoint" error. Now it's working for live environment but sandbox is still producing same error.